# Does java support class Foo<T super X> ,if no,why?

Tags: java, generics

Does java support `class Foo<T super X>` ,if no,why ?

Where T is a type parameter and X is a type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The `super` keyword in the context of Generics could only be used in combination with a wildcard (`?`) when declaring (consumer) variables or method parameters (consumers) that are of some Generic type.

For example, these are valid:

```
List<? super Something> list = someListReference;

public void methodThatPopulatesAList(List<? super Something> consumer) {
    ...
    list.add(new Something());
    ...
}
```

More info:

- [What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)
- [Wildcards in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use generic declaration `Foo<? super X>` in order to make things like this possible:

```
List<? super Integer> foo3 = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

but you can't use it in class declaration

Answer (score 0):

For Class :

```
class Foo<T extends X>
```

For Object :

```
Object<? extends X>
```

Comment: how is this related to the question? And how `Object` can be parametrized?